# How to manually populate array with objects?

Tags: java, arrays, object

I'm new to java and am having issues understanding how to populate an array with object manually. Reason I wan't to do this manually is because I have 40 objects I need to create where 20 object go to `arrayOne` and other 20 objects go to `arrayTwo`. Also each object has a unique parameter like "Texas" or "Canada" that needs to be set.

I would usually create an array like this:

```
long[] arrayOne;
arrayOne = new long[20];
```

and than populate it with, lets say numbers through a loop or manually. However now I am dealing with objects and am struggling to figure it out, I tried looking up answers here at StackOverflow, but was not able to understand what was going on there exactly.

If it helps, this is a constructor for my object

```
    // Plane Constructor
    public Plane (int i, String dest, String airl, String airc, double t) {

            planeID = i;
            destination = dest;
            airline = airl;
            aircraft = airc;
            time = t;

    }// END Plane Constructor
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would suggest using an `ArrayList` instead of an array, because a list can grow but an array is a fixed size. However, to answer your question:

```
Plane[] arrayOne = new Plane[20];
Plane[] arrayTwo = new Plane[20];

arrayOne[0] = new Plane(1001, "Timbuktu");
arrayOne[1] = new Plane(2930, "Siberia");
// etc.

arrayTwo[0] = new Plane(2019, "France");
arrayTwo[1] = new Plane(1222, "Italy");
// etc.
```

If you used an `ArrayList` it would be:

```
List<Plane> arrayOne = new ArrayList<Plane>();
planes.add(new Plane(1001, "Timbuktu"));
planes.add(new Plane(2930, "Siberia"));
// etc.
```

Or, if you're really fancy:

```
List<Plane> planes = new ArrayList<Plane>() {{
    add(new Plane(1001, "Timbuktu"));
    add(new Plane(2930, "Siberia"));
}};
```

In all cases you can iterate over the contents as follows:

```
for (Plane plane : arrayOne) {
    System.out.println(plane.getDestination());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Plane[] array = new Plane[10];
array[0] = new Plane(/*specify your parameters here*/)
```

Check out the [chapter 10](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-10.html) of Java Language Specification.

Comment: This is very ugly solution. What if you don't know how many object you'll have / retrieve from somewhere? Dynamic array should be much more efficient.

Comment: @Sajmom, OP say they're new to Java.  Probably haven't learned data structures yet.  You need to know how to use arrays.  So let OP walk before they run. Besides, OP specifically said they have 40 objects, 20 per array.

Comment: @Sajmon if I see the question "How do I use arrays in Java?", I show the example of arrays in Java. I don't understand people, who are telling to newbie "No-no-no, that's the wrong way, use ArrayList, assign it to a List interface, so you can change the realization later, and think about some pattern which you can use here". OP asked to explain him the basics of Java, which I did. If he need to know about ArrayList, he'll ask another question or learn it somewhere else.

Comment: Ok men. but you are here to suggest best approach or at least mention that there is another more efficient approach and i think that work with static or dynamic array is almost same maybe with dynamic more simple and comfortable. but ok i just mentioned that - no offence.

Comment: You can do both; answer the question and share your wisdom.

Answer (score 1):

You have to declare an array of objects (in this case `Plane`) just like you declare array of `long` - `Plane[] arrayOne = new Plane[20];`. Then you can access the elements using indices in the same manner. If you really have to populate it manually, you should do something like:

```
arrayOne[0] = new Plane(1, "foo", "bar", "baz", 1.0);
arrayOne[1] = new Plane(2, "fooo", "baar", "baaz", 2.0);
```

There are only two things that differ from the usage of `Object[]` array from `long[]` - type of the array and fact that at some point you have to use constructors to create objects. You can use a previously created object though.

Answer (score 0):

U first create the Plane array:

```
Plane[] planes = new Plane[20];
```

then each object:

```
planes[0] = new Plane(...);
```

...

Answer (score 0):

You can use a common `interface` if the elements of your `array` are not necessarily instances of `Plane`.

For instance:

package test;

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Flyer[] flyers = new Flyer[] { new Plane(), new Bird() };
            for (Flyer f: flyers) {
                // you can only access method "fly" here, because it's the only
                // method defined in your interface, but nothing
                // stops you from adding more methods, as long as you implement 
                // them in the (non-abstract) classes
                f.fly();
            }
    }
}

class Plane implements Flyer {
    // TODO id, destination, airline, etc. getters/setters
    @Override
    public void fly() {
        System.out.println("Weeee I'm flying!");
    }
}

class Bird implements Flyer {
    // TODO whatever properties / getters / setters
    @Override
    public void fly() {
        System.out.println("Chirp chirp");
    }
}

interface Flyer {
    void fly();
}
```

Output:

```
Weeee I'm flying!
Chirp chirp
```

Comment: Really appreciate you taking it further, but I think something like this is not my level yet, I wan't to learn basics first, however will definitely look into this latter on!

Comment: @Ilja sure! I might have misinterpreted your question a bit :)